# jQuery: iterate over nested elements using each

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this basic html structure:

```
<div class=a>
  <div class=m></div>
  <div class=m></div>
</div>
<div class=b>
  <div class=m></div>
  <div class=m></div>
</div>
```

now i want to iterate over all m's but also would like to know if i am in a or b.
using basic jquery syntax each i fail to do find this out.

```
$('.m').each(function(index) {
    // how do i know if this m is part of a or b ?
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$(this).parent().hasClass("a")` or `$(this).parent().hasClass("b")`

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(this).parent().hasClass('a'))
```

And same for b, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you care, then I'd separate the selectors like this:

```
$('.a .m').each(function(index) {
    // now I'm on .a items
});

$('.b .m').each(function(index) {
    // now I'm on .b items
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.m').each(function(index) {
    this.parentNode.getAttribute( "class" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, check the parent is `.a`

```
if($(this).parent().is('.a'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .closest method:

```
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.closest("a").length === 1) {
    alert("I'm in an a div");
}
else {
    alert("I'm in a b div");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the class of the parent element inside your function to identify if you are in 'a' or 'b'

```
$('.m').each(function() {
     var parentClass = $(this).parent().attr('class');
});
```

So, the parentClass var should have a value of either 'a' or 'b'